# In powershell, how can I retry a download after a certain amount of time if the file does not yet exist

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that downloads file like this:

```
powershell -Command `$progressPreference = 'silentlyContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest https://ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/data/nccf/com/cfs/prod/cfs/cfs.$m2/$m21z/6hrly_grib_04/pgbf$m2h.04.$m2h.grb2 -OutFile C:\OpenGrADS-2.2\data\cfs\cfs001.grb2`
```

Is it possible to check to see if the file exists before downloading, if it does, then download it, but if it doesn't, then wait a certain period of time before trying again.

Comment: Perhaps using [Start-BitsTransfer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitstransfer/start-bitstransfer) is more what you want. It has parameters `-RetryInterval` and `-RetryTimeout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following PowerShell script does the job.

It is copied from the post
[Download Remote File with Retry Support](https://jonlabelle.com/snippets/view/powershell/download-remote-file-with-retry-support):

```
# $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
 
function DownloadWithRetry([string] $url, [string] $downloadLocation, [int] $retries)
{
    while($true)
    {
        try
        {
            Invoke-WebRequest $url -OutFile $downloadLocation
            break
        }
        catch
        {
            $exceptionMessage = $_.Exception.Message
            Write-Host "Failed to download '$url': $exceptionMessage"
            if ($retries -gt 0) {
                $retries--
                Write-Host "Waiting 10 seconds before retrying. Retries left: $retries"
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
 
            }
            else
            {
                $exception = $_.Exception
                throw $exception
            }
        }
    }
}
 
#
# Usage
DownloadWithRetry -url "http://example.com/file.zip" -downloadLocation "C:\Downloads\file.zip" -retries 6
```